# How do i make a link list print out its contents in alphabetical order?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a single linked phonebook list with last names, first names, and values.
I am able to print them out in the order they were created, but not by value.  How can i modify this?  If you need to see anything else in the code let me know, but this function is my main concern.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const PhoneBook& p)  // out stream 
{
     if(p.head==NULL) 
     {
        cout << "is empty";
     }else
     {
         PhoneBookItem* item = p.head;
         for(int i=0; i < p.num; i++)
         {
            cout << item->lastname<< " ";
            cout << item->firstname<< " : ";
            cout << item->phone<<endl;
            item = item->next;
        }
     }
    return out;
```

Comment: Do you mean printing it out in alphabetical order or something? Because if you want to do that, you would need to reorder your entire list (or choose a different data structure).

Comment: +1 to what Dgrin91 said.
Use a Map and keep value as the key. The Map keeps it contents sorted by the key.

Comment: @dgrin91 , okay so i guess i have to make a temporary phonebook just to put the values in, then print it out.

notgain, sorry but i don't know how to use maps, that is beyond my class at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Sort the list, then print
Option 2: For every loop, search which item should be printed next. (Expensive)
Option 3: Use Hash/Dictionary approach instead of linked-list. Hash/Dictionary is 
          combination of fixed array and link list. They are good for 
          searching items faster than fixed array and linked-list.
Option 4: Use other data structure other than link list that has ability to access your data in order/alphabetically.

Comment: for this assignment i am only limited to option1 it seems.  how would i go about writing that?

Comment: @DeanMikkawa, the best way to sort a linked list is with a [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). A [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is easy to adapt to a linked list but it has poor performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting a linked list can be done in several ways.

1. Temporary reference array:  Allocate a temporary array or vector of pointers and traverse the linked list to fill it.  Sort the pointers. Library `std::sort` or `qsort` is fine for this.  Then traverse the sorted array to reset the "next" pointer of each node.  Finally release the temporary array storage.
2. Insertion sort: Pop elements off the list and re-insert in a new list at the correct sorted location.
3. Mergesort: It's not too hard to implement, and this runs much faster on long lists than insertion sort.  The algorithm is simple:  Split the list in 2.  Mergsort the halves recursively.  Then merge the results by repeatedly removing the smallest head and appending to the tail of a new list.
4. Quicksort: This is a bit tricky to implement efficiently with lists, but it *is* possible.  I won't discuss it because it's not a good early programming project, and mergesort is faster in many cases.

Here is some untested code for insertion sort:

```
PhoneBookItem* sorted = NULL;
while (p.head) {

    // Pop
    PhoneBookItem* head = p.head;
    p.head = head->next;
    head->next = NULL;

    // Find the place to insert.
    PhoneBookItem* lead = sorted;
    PhoneBookItem* trail = NULL;
    while (lead && lead->phone <= head->phone) {
        trail = lead;
        lead = lead->next;
    }

    // Insert either within the list or at the head.
    head->next = lead;
    if (trail)
        trail->next = head;
    else
        sorted = head;
}
p.head = sorted;
// Now print the sorted list as before...
```

Comment: It's also possible to do merge sort iteratively, that's my preference.

Comment: @MarkRansom Have fun. It's much more complicated and unlikely to be faster.  You'll probably end up duplicating what the compiler does with stack in the recursive expression.

Comment: That's an insertion sort, isn't it? There: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort are some other ideas for the case of huge data lists.

Comment: @harper Yes as #2 above says!  It's an insertion sort.  It's not good for huge data lists because its run time is O(n^2).  You want mergesort or quicksort, which are O(n log n) for those (in the case of most quicksorts, this time bound is expected, not absolute).